# Angular 7 bindear con formControlName un input de tipo file de mi vista

Tags: formularios, webforms, angular7

estoy actualizando mi `form` a la forma de hacerse en **Angular 7** he estado leyendo que necesito importar en mi `app.module.ts` esto : `import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` y meterlo en mis `imports` :

```
 imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

Luego en mi **vista** hacer uso del nuevo atributo del form `formControlName` , un ejemplo quedaria algo asi :

```
 <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control"  name="email">
```

Claro que para que funcione el **atributo** de la **vista** me dirijo a mi **fichero.component.ts** e **importo** :

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

Luego lo inyecto mediante el constructor :

```
constructor(private ps:PaisesService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
 this.usuario = new Usuario('','','','','','','','default_image.jpg');
 }
```

Mi siguiente paso es crear, digamos, la configuracion de mi `form` el nuevo `form` de **Angular 7** da la posibilidad de **desacoplar** la  **vista** y hacerlo practicamente todo desde el `fichero.component.ts` gracias a lo siguiente que muestro :

```
 //nuevo form (funcion)
  private buildForm(){
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre_real:'',
      apellidos : '',
      email :'',
      nombre_usuario : '',
      password : '',
      repetir_password:'',    
      img_perfil : 'img_perfil',
      pais : '',


    });
```

Con eso permito **bindear** mis controles (`inputs`) del **form** de mi **vista** sustituyendo al `[(ngModel)]` dandole asi mayor independizacion.

Y ya simplemente nos queda meter esa funciona dentro del `ngOnInit()` tal que asi :

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.cargarPaises();
    //nuevo form
    this.buildForm();

  }
```

Puesto en situacion voy a mi **problematica** :

Los **bindeos** de esta nueva forma (`this.formBuilder.group({})`) van de **maravilla** **PERO** cuando trato de bindear mi `input` de tipo `File` no me deja establecerle un `String`, a esto me refiero :

```
 private buildForm(){
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre_real:'',
      apellidos : '',
      email :'',
      nombre_usuario : '',
      password : '',
      repetir_password:'', 

     //Este 'img_perfil' es un input de type File, pero no me acepta Objetos File    ni String

      img_perfil : 'img_perfil',
      pais : '',


    });
```

Finalmente pregunto :

**¿Como pongo algo por defecto que me lo admita y tenga un minimo sentido contando que a la hora de verificarse solo me interesa saber si hay o no hay fichero subido?**

Comment: ¿Quieres añadirle un valor por defecto a un input de tipo File? Eso está prohibido en todos los navegadores por seguridad

Comment: Entonces que pongo en el json para hacer la configuracion de ese campo ? No pongo ni el campo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que deberías inicializarla a `null` y después comprobar en la verificación si es `null` o no.

```js
  private buildForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre_real: '',
      apellidos: '',
      email: '',
      nombre_usuario: '',
      password: '',
      repetir_password: '',
      img_perfil: null,
      pais: ''
    });
  }
```

Saludos

Comment: Si, gracias eso hice.